# How to prevent "SQL Injection" in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I am building a pretty complex predicate in several iterations, and want to supply the matching values right away in the predicate.

Instead of:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"departmentName like[c] %@"];
```

I want to do:

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"departmentName like[c] '%@'", departmentName];
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:str];

Since this is a dumb substitution, I guess it's possible to "hack" the predicate accidently by entering garbage.

I couldn't find anything that would "magically quote" that value for me.

Reason is, that I need to build up a complex predicate in several iterations, so I have to construct a big predicate string. Templates don't work with SUBQUERY. So I need to provide the values right away in the string, since I don't want to make 20 different predicate initializations depending on how many values I have for the predicate format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `NSComparisonPredicate` directly, and bypass the predicate format issues.

```
NSPredicate *fetchPredicate = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression:[NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"departmentName"]
                                                                 rightExpression:[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:searchTerm]
                                                                        modifier:NSDirectPredicateModifier
                                                                            type:NSLikePredicateOperatorType
                                                                         options:0];
```

Have a read through the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html) "Creating Predicates Directly in Code", and check the class reference for [`NSComparisonPredicate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscomparisonpredicate)