# How to escape a NSString to prevent SQLInjection with Core Data

Tags: ios, sql-injection

what is the best way to escape a Search String from an input field to prevent SQLInjections?

Is there an `mysql_real_escape_string` method like in PHP or should i manually replace/escape the different characters like: `OR, AND, LIKE, WHERE, DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE, FROM, GROUP BY, ORDER BY` and so on?

Comment: I don't think that you have to take care about that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent "SQL Injection" in Core Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076894/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-core-data)

Comment: also as Nick said - have you tried to inject?  I would imagine frameworks like CoreData would using params when working with sqlite eliminating sql injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

closed with the answer from: @Nick Weaver:

> I don't think that you have to take care about that.

Answer (score -4):

Using mysql_real_escape_string for a search query is a good option. However you need to be aware of 2 things :

1) If you apply this solution in an other situation, make sure the parameter is always quoted when it gets integrated. In short, mysql_real_escape_string does not protect you against numeric parameters. Here are 2 examples :

```
$bad_sql = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);

$good_sql  = "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE name='" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "'";
```

2) The second thing to consider is that mysql_real_escape_string does not escape wildcard characters (% and _). You should not worry about that. However, a "perfect" solution escape those characters.

For more information you can take a look at http://www.sqlinjection.net.

FYI : The official mysql_real_escape_string reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php.

Comment: i don't need PHP SQL escaping

Comment: Also even in PHP please don't use this. Theres a long history of the mysql escape functions succumbing to various unicode attacks. ALWAYS use prepared statements, without exception