# Correct way to create a NSPredicate

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

i found 2 different ways to create a NSPredicate.

Way 1:

```
NSExpression *exprName = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"name"];
NSExpression *exprFilter = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: name ]; 
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSComparisonPredicate predicateWithLeftExpression: exprName 
                                                              rightExpression: exprFilter 
                                                                     modifier: NSDirectPredicateModifier  
                                                                         type: NSContainsPredicateOperatorType 
                                                                      options: NSCaseInsensitivePredicateOption];
```

Way 2:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name CONTAINS[c] %@", name];
```

What is the best way to create a NSPredicate and also prevent SQLInjection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first way is useful if you are setting up a complex predicate programmatically. Other than that, the second way is fine. You don't have to worry about SQL injection with Core Data.

[relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821570/how-to-escape-a-nsstring-to-prevent-sqlinjection-with-core-data)

[also relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076894/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-core-data)