# NSPredicate pass "multiple" parameters by name [in Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters to NSPredicate by naming them instead of `%@`

For example, I have a `directly-passed` parameters `me` and `you`.

```
public static func ConversationByUserId( userId : String ) -> [Message] {

    // Either Created By me and sent to you.
    // Or, created by you and sent to me


    let me = UserRepo.GetLoggedInUser()?.id

    var format = "( createdBy == '" + me! + "'  && createdTo == '"  +  userId + "') "
    format += " || ( createdBy == '" + userId + "'  && createdTo == '" + me! + "') "


    print(format)
    //prints: ( createdBy == '1'  && createdTo == '5')  || ( createdBy == '5'  && createdTo == '1')


    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:  format)

    return Filter(predicate);


}
```

Note: `Filter(predicate)` carries out the operation and returns the result. So far so good. I get expected results. But this can have problems like SQL attacks, I guess.

Can I do something like below: If so, how?

```
  var format = "( createdBy == @me  && createdTo == @you ) "
  format += " || ( createdBy == @you  && createdTo == @me ) "


 let predicate = NSPredicate(format:  format, [ "me" : me, "you" : you ])
```

So far I have achieved is:

```
    format = "( createdBy == %@  && createdTo == %@ ) "
    format += " || ( createdBy == %@  && createdTo == %@ ) "


    let predicate = NSPredicate(format:  format, me!, you, me!, you)
```

Comment: This answer and others talk about using NSComparisonPredicate to prevent SQL injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076894/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-core-data

Comment: @Moshe, Does not make sense to me. If you know post the answer in swift?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use NSPredicate's `predicateWithSubstitutionVariables` (see the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPredicate/predicateWithSubstitutionVariables:)).  Create the predicate as usual, using "$variable" in place of the values you want to substitute in:

```
var format = "( createdBy == $me  && createdTo == $you ) "
format += " || ( createdBy == $you  && createdTo == $me ) "
let predicate = NSPredicate(format:  format)
```

then create a dictionary with the variable names and the values you want to pass:

```
let subVars = ["me" : me!, "you" : you!]
```

and finally create the predicate with the variable names replaced by your values:

```
let finalPredicate = predicate.predicateWithSubstitutionVariables(subVars)
```

Comment: This is super duper for complex fetches, elegant and easy to write/read and understand even months later. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

**NOTE:** You are NOT going to have SQL injection attacks in an iOS application.  Unless you are letting the user type in SQL and then you are sending that SQL to a *server* somewhere, there is no risk of a SQL injection attack.

Core Data and `NSPredicate` don't work that way.

Having said that; you can use `NSExpression` instances and build an `NSComparisonPredicate` from the combination of the `NSExpression` pieces.

```
let me = 1123 //Example value

let test = [["createdBy":1124,"name":"Fred"],["createdBy":1123,"name":"Jane"]] as NSArray

let lhs = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "createdBy")
let rhs = NSExpression(forConstantValue: me)

let predicate = NSComparisonPredicate(leftExpression: lhs, rightExpression: rhs, modifier: NSComparisonPredicateModifier.DirectPredicateModifier, type: NSPredicateOperatorType.EqualToPredicateOperatorType, options: [])

let results = test.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)
print("Results: \(results)")
```

Combine `NSComparisonPredicate` with `NSCompoundPredicate` and you can build anything you want.